# GNOME 3.2 Screen keyboard, when opened onboard pops up

Tags: 11.10, gnome, keyboard, accessibility, onboard

When I enable the "screen keyboard" from the accessibility next to that the GNOME onscreen keyboard is started onboard is also opened. Is there a way to prevent this?!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/879942). But if you're planning to use only Gnome Shell instead of Unity you could uninstall onboard

```
sudo apt-get remove onboard
```

**If you do this you won't be able to use onboard on LightDM.**

Anyway, it seems possible to use LightDM with Caribou, but the unity-greeter is coded to use Onboard, so it would be necessary to write a patch for unity-greeter.

EDIT. *Another workaround is to remove onboard autostart from /etc/xdg/autostart without removing onboard.*

Comment: Well not the most suitable solution but ok.

Comment: Hm In my case I can open the keyboard without onboard showing up